# How to write regular expression to find all function names in a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to know writing regular expression for the following string to find all function names.

```
"var sampleFunc = function(){return 'hello';}alert(sampleFunc());function sampleTest(){var sampleTestVar = 'one';};var sampleFunc = function(){return 'hello';}alert(sampleFunc());function sampleTest(){var sampleTestVar = 'one';};"
```

The above string contains simple JS program. I would like to get the output for the above string as,

```
["sampleFunc", "sampleTest", "sampleFunc", "sampleTest"]
```

Help me in writing regular expression for the above problem.

Comment: Please [help others reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What have you tried?

Comment: You cannot do this with a regex.  You will need to parse this as JS.

Comment: To add to Oliver's comment, you can't do this because JavaScript is not a regular language.

Comment: Actually, My code really looks messy. So I did not want to confuse people with my code. I really wanted to ask what I was looking for and I did. Now I did get the answer from "ibrahim mahir" (see below for his answer). I am happy! Thank you so much for your contribution ctwheels. @ctwheels

Comment: Ok. I did get the answer from "ibrahim mahir" (see below for his answer). I understand your point that without parsing it I cannot get the correct function names. The solution given by "ibrahim mahir" is more than enough for me.Thank you very much for your contribution Oliver. @OliverCharlesworth

Comment: Ok. Thank you. @Amy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, here is another approach. In this safer and reliable approach, I used [**`acorn`**](https://github.com/ternjs/acorn) which is a library used by CodeMirror's [TernJS](http://ternjs.net/) for parsing javascript. [CodeMirror](https://codemirror.net/) is a very powerful web-based code editor, used almost everywhere (even here on SO).

**The code:**

First, here is the code:

HTML:

```
<script src="path/to/accorn.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/walk.js"></script>
```

Javascript:

```
function getFunctionNames(codeString) {
    var names = [];
    acorn.walk.simple(acorn.parse(codeString), {
        AssignmentExpression: function(node) {
            if(node.left.type === "Identifier" && (node.right.type === "FunctionExpression" || node.right.type === "ArrowFunctionExpression")) {
                names.push(node.left.name);
            }
        },
        VariableDeclaration: function(node) {
            node.declarations.forEach(function (declaration) {
                if(declaration.init && (declaration.init.type === "FunctionExpression" || declaration.init.type === "ArrowFunctionExpression")) {
                    names.push(declaration.id.name);
                }
            });
        },
        Function: function(node) {
            if(node.id) {
                names.push(node.id.name);
            }
        }
    });
    return names;
}
```

**Example:**

```js
function getFunctionNames(codeString) {
    var names = [];
    acorn.walk.simple(acorn.parse(codeString), {
        AssignmentExpression: function(node) {
            if(node.left.type === "Identifier" && (node.right.type === "FunctionExpression" || node.right.type === "ArrowFunctionExpression")) {
                names.push(node.left.name);
            }
        },
        VariableDeclaration: function(node) {
            node.declarations.forEach(function (declaration) {
                if(declaration.init && (declaration.init.type === "FunctionExpression" || declaration.init.type === "ArrowFunctionExpression")) {
                    names.push(declaration.id.name);
                }
            });
        },
        Function: function(node) {
            if(node.id) {
                names.push(node.id.name);
            }
        }
    });
    return names;
}

console.log(getFunctionNames(`

var sampleFunc = function() {
    return 'hello';
}
/*
  function thisIsNotReallyAFunction() {} 
*/

alert(sampleFunc());
function /* undesired comment */ sampleTest() {
    var sampleTestVar = 'one';
};
var sampleFunc=
// still OK!
function() {
    return 'hello';
}
alert(sampleFunc());
function
// all sotrts of comments
sampleTest()
/* Even
 * Block ones
 */

{
    var sampleTestVar = 'one';
};
var sampleFuncEDIT;
sampleFunEDIT = function (){};
var functionNameEDIT = "sampleFunc";

`));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/acorn/5.2.1/acorn.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/acorn/5.2.1/walk.js"></script>
```

**Explanation:**

For a thorough explanation, check out `acorn`'s GitHub page [here](https://github.com/ternjs/acorn).

`acorn` is split into a bunch of source files, each responsible for a specific job. We used only `acorn.js` and `walk.js`.

`acorn.js` is used for parsing. It contains a lot of useful functions used for parsing such as `acorn.parse()`, `acorn.parseExpressionAt()`, `acorn.tokenizer()`, ... We are only interested in `acorn.parse` which return an AST ([abstract syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree). Which is basically a tree structure of nodes. A node describes a meaningful chunk of code, it could be of an assignment, a function call, a variable declaration, ... A node will be an object that has properties describing that chunk of code. It will have a `type` property, a `start` (where the chunk of code starts), an `end` (where it ends), and each type of node will have some additional properties only used for that type.

Now, that we have the AST tree, we can walk through it ourselves (they are just a bunch of nested objects anyway). Or use `acorn`'s way: `acorn` provides us with a very powerful way of walking this tree. The functions are in the file `walk.js`. Same as `acorn.js`, `walk.js` also contain a bunch of useful functions, we only need `walk.simple()`. What `walk.simple` does, is that it takes a tree and another object as parameters. The tree is our AST tree (returned by `acorn.parse`), and the object is an object of this form:

```
{
    [NodeType1]: function(node) { /* node is of type NodeType1 */ },
    [NodeType2]: function(node) { /* node is of type NodeType2 */ },
    ...
}
```

As `walk.simple` walks the tree, node by node, it checks if there is a function for the current node's type, if there is one, it will call that function (passing to it the node itself) and proceed to the next node, if not it will ignore the node and proceed to the next node. From the various node types we are only interested in:

1. `Function`:

Which is basically a normal function declaration such as:

```js
var codeString = `
function f () {
};

function someName() {
};

() => {
};`;

acorn.walk.simple(acorn.parse(codeString), {
    Function: function(node) {
        console.log(node);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/acorn/5.2.1/acorn.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/acorn/5.2.1/walk.js"></script>
```

Some of the additional properties pairs are: `id` (which is an identifier node, used for this function declaration, or `null` if the function doesn't have one). The identifier node, if exist, have a `name` property, which will be the name of our function.

2. `VariableDeclaration`:

Which is any variable declaration using `var`, `let` or `const`:

```js
var codeString = `
var e, f = function() {}, g = () => {};
`;

acorn.walk.simple(acorn.parse(codeString), {
    VariableDeclaration: function(node) {
        console.log(node);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/acorn/5.2.1/acorn.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/acorn/5.2.1/walk.js"></script>
```

This type of nodes will also have some additional properties such as `declarations` which is an array of all declarations (the example above shows 3: one for `e`, one for `f` and one for `g`). The declarations are also nodes, which have the additional `id` (the identifier node) and `init` (the initialization object which is a node describing the value we assign to the variable at initialization or `null` if it doesn't exist). We are only interested if `init.type` was a function node (either `"FunctionExpression"` or `"ArrowFunctionExpression"`).

3. `AssignmentExpression`:

Which is any assignment using `=` (not to be confused with variable initialization):

```js
var codeString = `
someVar = function() {
}
`;

acorn.walk.simple(acorn.parse(codeString), {
    AssignmentExpression: function(node) {
        console.log(node);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/acorn/5.2.1/acorn.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/acorn/5.2.1/walk.js"></script>
```

This node object will have an additional `left` (left-hand operand) and `right` (right-hand operand) properties, which are both nodes. We are only interested if the `left` node was an identifier node and the `right` node was a function node.

**Notes:**

1. `acorn.parse` throws an error if the actual code string has a syntax error in it. So you may want to wrap its call in a `try-catch` statement to handle that case, and then pass its result to `acorn.walk.simple` if only no errors were thrown.
2. If you don't want to include a type, just remove it from the object and provide only the types you want. Say for example you don't want to include `AssignmentExpression`, then just remove it from the object passed to `acorn.walk.simple`
3. You can have different arrays for different types of functions. Same as of my other answer: `varFunctions`, `functionFunction` and `assignmentFunctions`.

I hope this is helpful and understandable.

Comment: Hi ibrahim! It is good to hear another anwer from you. You mentioned this answer as safer and reliable. I would like to try this answer. You asked to include acorn.js and walk.js to run this example. Where do I find those JS files? Thanks and regards!

Comment: Hi ibrahim! I have installed acron node package. When I used getFunctionName function given in this answer, It did not list me assignment expression functions (example: TreeView.prototype.addChild = function(options) {). So I have updated the function. Please look at the updated code [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/f40ovenz/). I am not sure if it is a correct way of doing it. Thanks.! @ibrahim mahrir

Answer (score 1):

First you have to remove undesired comments that may contain confusing content (see the example bellow), then remove all new lines and finally remove block comments. Then you can match the function names. There are two types, ones declared using `funcName = function` and others declared using `function funcName`. Both need different regexps.

**Working code:**

```js
function getNames(text) {
  text = text.replace(/\/\/.*?\r?\n/g, "")                                 // first, remove line comments
             .replace(/\r?\n/g, " ")                                       // then remove new lines (replace them with spaces to not break the structure)
             .replace(/\/\*.*?\*\//g, "");                                 // then remove block comments
             
  // PART 1: Match functions declared using: var * = function 
  var varFuncs      = (text.match(/[$A-Z_][0-9A-Z_$]*\s*=\s*function[( ]/gi) || []) // match any valid function name that comes before \s*=\s*function
                           .map(function(tex) {                            // then extract only the function names from the matches
                             return tex.match(/^[$A-Z_][0-9A-Z_$]*/i)[0];
                           });

  // PART 2: Match functions declared using: function * 
  var functionFuncs = (text.match(/function\s+[^(]+/g) || [])              // match anything that comes after function and before (
                           .map(function(tex) {                            // then extarct only the names from the matches
                             return tex.match(/[$A-Z_][0-9A-Z_$]*$/i)[0];
                           });
  return {
    var: varFuncs,
    function: functionFuncs
  };
}


var text =
`var sampleFunc = function() {
    return 'hello';
}
/*
  function thisIsNotReallyAFunction() {} 
*/

alert(sampleFunc());
function /* undesired comment */ sampleTest() {
    var sampleTestVar = 'one';
};
var sampleFunc=
// still OK!
function() {
    return 'hello';
}
alert(sampleFunc());
function
// all sotrts of comments
sampleTest()
/* Even
 * Block ones
 */

{
    var sampleTestVar = 'one';
};
var sampleFuncEDIT = function (){};
var functionNameEDIT = "sampleFunc";
`;

var names = getNames(text);
console.log(names);
```

**Notes:**

1. Function names can contain various other unicode characters that can't be matched using the above regex `[$A-Z_][0-9A-Z_$]*`. [ECMA Specs](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf).
2. Even if we remove the comments, there could be other factors that may confuse the function (for example strings). The above presents a simple use case, if you are looking for an advanced way of doing this then you need to parse the string, not use regexes.

Here are some examples where the function won't work:

```
var text = "var dummyString = 'function thisShouldntBeMatchedButWillBe';"

var text = "someString = 'this /* will confuse the comment removal'";

// ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ibrahim. Your code looks very clean and understandable. I am new to regular expression and tried writing code myself and it ended up with nearly 100 lines of code. Your code look lot simpler and working REALLY good. Thank you once again for your good help. I need to mention, Your answer also looks very neat and well explained with drawbacks.@ibrahim mahir

Comment: @JeffrinJohn You're very welcome! I'm glad I could help.

Comment: @ibrahm mahrir: getName function doesn't handle the following 2 cases which I found. I) when there is a space in between function and (. Example: var sampleFunc = function (){}; ii) when a variable name has function keyword in it. Example: var functionName = "sampleFunc"; How to update getName function to handle these two cases. Thank you.

Comment: @JeffrinJohn **i)** is already handled. **ii)** was a stupid mistake on my part: I intended to do `function\s+` but forgot and wrote `function\s*`. Check now!

Comment: @JeffrinJohn actually **i)** and **ii)** are caused by the same stupid mistake which is fixed by changing `\s*` to `\s+`.

Comment: @ibrahm mahrir: Thank you once again ibrahm. Now getName function handles above said two instances.

Comment: @JeffrinJohn And once again, you're welcome! BTW, I always wanted to look into `acorn` (which is an amazing lib). I found this to be the perfect occasion. So I had my self some very good time playing around with it and made another version of `getFunctionNames`. A reliable one that you can use with surety. Check it out in my other answer (I really hope the explanation is clear). And thank you for this wonderful time I had.

Answer (score -1):

```
var re=/(\w+)\(\)/g
// var re=/([\w_-]+)\(\)/g 
var rslt = s.match(re)
```

Still keep it simple.

Comment: Thank you so much for your contribution moutonjr. @moutonjr

Comment: @JeffrinJohn No pb! :)